# tkinter button only visible when a word is in a textbox python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, button, find

I'm trying to create a button in Tkinter that only appears (becoming visible) when it finds the word "hello" in a textbox.

I could imagine using Threads, and Global variables but i do not know how to code it,
I've imagined something like :

```
import Tkinter as *
from threading import Thread

window = Tk()
active = True

def check_for_word():
    global active
    textbox1 = textbox.get("1,0", "end")
    while active == True:
         if "hello" in textbox1:
              button.pack()
         else:
              button.pack_forget()

save_button = Button(window)

textbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window)
textbox.pack()

threading = Thread (target=check_for_word)
threading.start()

window.mainloop()
```

this is something I would suspect to work but ends up not, the button either doesn't show at all like the code isn't even running, or the thread doesn't work properly. So am I doing something wrong, if so, can you help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: `"1,0"` shoulde be `"1.0"`, why are you using Python 2.x? it is a deprecated version and shouldn't be used, second: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue. When You pack the button set `active = False` and no need for it to be global

Comment: Using `threading` and `tkinter` isn't a good idea. Sometimes `tkinter` can crash if you call it from another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make use of threads to do this, you can use tkinter event bindings instead.

```
def check_for_word():
    if "hello" in textbox.get("1.0", "end"):
        save_button.pack()
    else:
        save_button.pack_forget()

save_button = Button(window)

textbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window)
textbox.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda event:check_for_word())
textbox.pack()
```

To make a binding, you use `widget.bind`. In this case, the widget is `textbox` and it's binding to `<KeyRelease>`, which is when the user releases a key. It then calls `check_for_word` when a key is released. (The `lambda` part is to ignore the event parameter). `check_for_word` then does what it did before.

Comment: Why not add `else: save_button.pack_forget()`? I think OP would want that.

Comment: Good idea, I'd missed that. Thanks

Comment: also instead of pack_forget, i  use save_button.place, so i would need to use save_button.place_forget

Comment: Glad I could help and yes, you would need `place_forget`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the textbox1 assignment inside the while loop and before the `if` condition, otherwise it will check the value one time before entering the loop and will keep checking always the same value.

I also want to point out that the `in` operator is case sensitive and return True if it find even just **a substring** inside the variable you are checking and not just the precise single word (but I'm not shure if this is intensional).

For the while loop you don't necessarily need a global variable, you could just use `while True:` if you want it to continuously check the condition (if you want the button to disappear after the user cancel the word).